# How to un-override the onReceive method in BroadcastReceiever

Tags: android, overriding, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that replies to any received SMS with a default message. The app works, however it also works when I close the app. Is there anyway I can un-override the onReceive method for BroadcastReceiver, so that once I close the app, it won't use my version of the onReceieve method? If not, what's the best way to fix this problem?

```
//SMS.java
package net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging;

import net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SMS extends Activity 
{
    Button btnExit;
    static EditText txtMessage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        btnExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                
                finish();
            }
        });        
    }    

    public static String getMessage(){
        return txtMessage.getText().toString();
    }
}
______________________________________________________________________________________
//SMSReceiver.java
package net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";   
                sendSms(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(),SMS.getMessage());
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }         
    }
    private void sendSms(String phonenumber,String message)
    {
      SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
      manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a boolean which decides whether to execute your code or the super's onRecieve method. Then just override the onPause method of the activity and toggle the boolean flag.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this, thanks! I would upvote but I need 15 reputation to do so:p

Answer (score 0):

Try having a `SharedPreference`, a boolean that states whether the application is running or not.

In the onCreate(), have the boolean set as true, and override the onDestroy() to set it to false.

Then, before sending the sms, check whether the boolean is true or false. The only way to check this is through a service, so you will need to have the sendSms method within a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)